# customizing synchronized in java

Tags: java

I know this is kind of wired requirement and I can achieve the below requirement with various locks available in Java.But I want to minimize the effort in development.

Requirement: My existing code base uses *synchronized* keyword in method level for thread safety in various places. Now the same code base can be used by multiple tenant, so we have make the synchronizations also to be tenant aware.

Possible Solutions:

1. Change code to use different lock for different tenant and change every method to add the lock in start and unlock in the end.
2. Somehow customize the *synchronized* keyword to *customSynchronized* keyword and will behave tenant aware manner.

I know the solution 1 will definitely work but it will be hell lot of code changes, so I need help from the expert if the solution 2 is possible at all, even if it is complex.

Now:

```
 public synchronized void method1(){
    // some processing on share object
}
```

Tryying to make:

```
 public customSynchronized void method1(){
    // some processing on share object
}
```

Comment: for custom Synchronization java introduced locks i guess

Comment: If you're asking the question, safe to say that `2` is not possible. You _could_ potentially use AOP based on annotations, e.g. a custom `@TenantCritical` with an annotation processor to inject the code at compile time. I would completely rethink the design of the code however - keep the `synchronized` blocks but have one **instance** per tenant - this is trivial with a DI framework.

Comment: I strongly agree you revisit your design.  It does not quite make sense to me that you can use same instance for multi-tanent but you need to only synchronize in tenant-level: if your internal state is segregated by tenant (so different thread for different tenant can modify state concurrently), you should synchronize on the segregated data for specific tenant